# How to pass a DataFrame column through a function and add the result back as a new column? Python

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have a dataframe with four columns and want to pass the elements in one column (e.g. column `b`) through a function, and then add the result back into the dataframe as a new, fifth column. The problem is, that the output is only one number for example `[6.782468322626846]`. But I would expect 4 numbers. What am I doing wrong?

The DataFrame `df_prices` looks something like this:

```
        a       b      c  d
0  354.24  322.02     10  3.729
1  352.04  320.04     10  3.906
2  349.98  318.17     10  4.072
3  347.82  316.20     10  4.246
```

The function needs to take column `b` and pass it to a function.

```
interest = 0.02
mean_end_price = 400
T = 1
exchange = 1.1199

def func(b):
    for i in b:
        b = b * (1 + interest) * np.sqrt(T)
        nvp_price = ((mean_end_price - b)/(1 + interest) * np.sqrt(T))/(ratio * exchange)
output.append(nvp_price)

df_prices['e'] = func(df_prices['b'])
```

Comment: can you please define what 'ratio' is?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be solved using numpy and vectorization, see example below:

```
import pandas
import numpy as np
#         a       b      c  d
# 0  354.24  322.02     10  3.729
# 1  352.04  320.04     10  3.906
# 2  349.98  318.17     10  4.072
# 3  347.82  316.20     10  4.246

df_prices = pandas.DataFrame(columns=['a','b','c','d'], index=['0','1','2','3'])
df_prices.loc['0'] = [354.24,  322.02,     10,  3.729]
df_prices.loc['1'] = [352.04 , 320.04  ,   10 , 3.906]
df_prices.loc['2'] = [349.98 , 318.17  ,   10 , 4.072]
df_prices.loc['3'] = [347.82 , 316.20  ,   10  ,4.246]
print(df_prices)



interest = 0.02
mean_end_price = 400
T = 1
exchange = 1.1199
ratio = .5
def func(b):
    b = np.asarray(b)
    b = b * (1 + interest) * np.sqrt(T)
    nvp_price = ((mean_end_price - b)/(1 + interest) * np.sqrt(T))/(ratio * exchange)
    return nvp_price

df_prices['e'] = list(func(df_prices['b']))

print(df_prices)
```

Comment: This is wonderful. Can you help me understand what that does? Also, I am getting a ```TypeError: can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'float'```

Comment: In which line? I am not getting any error running the above program. Are you using python 3.6 or above?

Comment: I think it is because in my code I have not vectorised the data like you have above. Is it necessary to do this manually? Because my real dataframe is very long.

Comment: you have to change sequence b into numpu vector b by asarray function otherwise vectorization wont work it works only in the realm of numy arrays

Answer (score 0):

try to use *apply*

```
df_prices['e'] = df_prices['b'].apply(lambda x:func(x))
```